# $x+\dfrac{1}{y}=y+\dfrac{1}{z}=z+\dfrac{1}{x}$, prove that $xyz=1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x>0$, $y>0$ and $z>0$ such that $x\neq y $ , $y\neq z$ and $x\neq z$. If $x+\dfrac{1}{y}=y+\dfrac{1}{z}=z+\dfrac{1}{x}$, prove that $xyz=1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice that
\begin{align} x-y &= \frac{y-z}{yz} \\
y-z &= \frac{z-x}{xz} \\
z-x &= \frac{x-y}{xy}.
\end{align}
Now multiply.

Comment: nice. but what you get is $(xyz)^2 = 1$, which mean $xyz$ could be $-1$ as well.

Comment: @ElBazzi by hypothesis $x,y,z>0$.

Comment: OH okay.. My bad, i did not see that

Comment: btw it seems the assumptions of this question cannot be satisfied. Indeed $x,y,z$ cannot all be $1$ so suppose $x\neq1$. Then $1-x=xy(z-1/y)=xy(x-1/x)=y(x^2-1)$, so $1=-y(x+1)<0$.